# ImportError: No module named lines

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

```
from lines import lines 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import lines
ImportError: No module named lines
```

This is taken from [this](http://packages.python.org/pycha/examples.html) example for Pycha. How I can install this Module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module `lines.py` is part of the Pycha examples. You can find a copy of that module [in that directory](https://bitbucket.org/lgs/pycha/src/bb277e830d92/examples/lines.py).

To follow the example correctly, you should call the `examples/barchart.py` example while still maintaining the rest of the `examples` directory. Then it will work.

If you want to create an own script based on the example, you’ll have to replace that module with your own code/data.

Comment: i have a question about create a module like lines.py , i create a code and from the code i retrieve the x,y-axis values , how i create like this module ??

Comment: @s.jor.ibra If this answer has helped you, why don't you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The module should be in a file name `lines.py` that is somewhere in your [module search-path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: I used python 2.7 , and i found linecache.py Is this module like lines.py ??

Comment: @s.jor.ibra: I have no idea what you think `lines` is. I have never heard of it.

Comment: i work for make a lineChart , and i need to lines to make the graph

Comment: @s.jor.ibra: Well, are you sure you have installed Pycha correctly? You can find instructions [here](http://packages.python.org/pycha/installation.html).

Comment: I used easy_install to install Pycha , so yes installed correctly , but there is no change .

Comment: @s.jor.ibra: Sorry, can't help you there. You could try searching for `lines.py` in the Pycha-directory tree. Maybe it is part of their examples?